# spark vs flink vs m/r for batch processing

Tags: mysql, hadoop, apache-spark, batch-processing, apache-flink

I was wondering if you can help me decide which one is best suitable to use in my case.

Use case:
I want to batch process ~200M events that are stored in apache kafka and ~20M rows in different sql tables per day. Data in rows represent states of users and events in kafka change these states. Events in kafka are well partitioned (all events for one user are stored in exactly one kafka segment),but still, there are more users than kafka segments.

(EDIT)
State updates can`t be handled in real-time as events come from different sources in different times. All events have timestamps with proper timezone, but events might be observed late which will yield in shifted timestamp. There are business rules how to handle these

I know to compute user state for any given time if all events and starting state is available.

Output:

- consistent final user states are stored in mysql
- writes during computation to other sources (kafka, text files, etc..) can occur based on current state

All of them are able to read and group data so I can process them, but as far as I know:

- spark and flink can work withou hadoop (so far I don't have any stable cluster)
- Spark has problem with dealing more data than RAM available (?)
- with Flink I`m not sure if I can combine data from data stream (kafka) and table (sql)
- with m/r I need to set up hadoop cluster

Also in the future there might be 100M events per hour and there will be functional hadoop cluster.

Comment: "I know to compute user state in any given time if all events and starting state is available." .. How do you know that all events for a given user are present?
I'm asking this because I'm wondering whether you can actually implement this using Flink and its support for event time. With that, you could work on events from different sources with different time.

Comment: 1. I realised my mistake, it should be "I know to compute user state FOR any given time if all events and starting state are available" 
2. events have to arrive in a given time window (lets say 2 hours) otherwise they are rejected
3. events have timestamps with timezone, but sources are not reliable and one can detect that state change too late e.g. system A detects that somebody enters the room at 10:00 but system B detects that the door was opened at 10:01 (which is actually not possible as you can`t enter room without opening door) - I know how to handle these exceptions